# Magento 2 Mini-cart doesn't close when click on outside in iPhones

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

How can we close the mini cart popup on Magento 2? (clicking outside is not working). I have already tried the following method on **footer.phtml.** It's working on android phones and browsers but iPhones, it is not working.

```
<script>
   require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
     jQuery(document).ready( function() {

      $('body').click(function (event)
      {
         element = $(event.target);
         if(element.parents('.skip-link.skip-cart').length1 || element.hasClass('skip-cart'))
           {
             return;
           }

           var parent = $('.minicart-wrapper').parents('.skip-content');
           var link = parent.siblings('.skip-link');

         if (element.parents('.minicart-wrapper').length == 0)
           {
             parent.removeClass('skip-active');
             link.removeClass('skip-active');
           }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

[image: Minicart Popup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **`footer.phtml`** above with your **`jquery`**, just add this:

```
<body style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="">
</body>
```

Comment: Now It's working. Thanks for the help